# Error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" on remote server

Tags: c#, ssl

I have a fairly simple code that worked until recently, until the site to which it sends the data is not switched to https.
In debug mode (on the local host) I use a proxy with access by domain login and password. In release mode, I use another proxy that does not require credentials.
I tried to add

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

and it didn't work! Rather only half. The request is sent if the credentials are sent as in debug mode, but fall off with the exception of "The underlying connection was closed: if you use DefaultCredentials. What advice can you give me?

```
#if DEBUG //OK
        NetworkCredential proxyCreds = new NetworkCredential(
            "login",
            "password"
        );

        WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://bproxy.com:3131", false)
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
            Credentials = proxyCreds,
        };

        HttpClient client = null;
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = proxy,
            PreAuthenticate = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        };

        client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
#else   // NOT OK
        HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://bproxy.com:3128"))
        };

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
#endif

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://url.com");
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | 
            SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
           {"_method", "POST" },
           { "data[User][email]", user },
           { "data[User][password]", pass }
        };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        var responseString = Post(client, "/", content);
```

Comment: It's a network error. The network situation is different per environment, of course. You will need to do some basic root cause analysis. Check the server logs to see if any request was received. Try the same request with a browser. Etc. It could easily have nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to whitelist those proxy address you're using on the network your hosting it to. Whitelist the IP or proxy address including the port

Communicate with your network team.